Flutter Riverpod Image is not removing from UI
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

final tryProvider = StateNotifierProvider<TryController, TryState>((ref) {
  return TryController();
});

class Try extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final tryState = ref.watch(tryProvider);
    final tryController = ref.read(tryProvider.notifier);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              if (tryState.imageFile == null) {
                tryController.pickLogoImage();
              }
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 76,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.20,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xffD9D9D9),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                image: tryState.imageFile != null
                    ? DecorationImage(
                        image: FileImage(tryState.imageFile!),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      )
                    : null,
              ),
              child: tryState.imageFile != null
                  ? Stack(
                      children: [
                        Positioned(
                          right: 0,
                          top: 0,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              tryController.removeLogoImage();
                            },
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.close,
                              color: Colors.red,
                              size: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  : Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "Logo",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
                            color: Color(0xff8D8D8D),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                    ),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              if (tryState.imageLogo == null) {
                tryController.pickLogo();
              }
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 76,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.20,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xffD9D9D9),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                image: tryState.imageLogo != null
                    ? DecorationImage(
                        image: FileImage(tryState.imageLogo!),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      )
                    : null,
              ),
              child: tryState.imageLogo != null
                  ? Stack(
                      children: [
                        Positioned(
                          right: 0,
                          top: 0,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              tryController.removeLogo();
                            },
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.close,
                              color: Colors.red,
                              size: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  : Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "Logo",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
                            color: Color(0xff8D8D8D),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                    ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TryState {
  final File? imageFile;
  final File? imageLogo;

  TryState({this.imageFile, this.imageLogo});

  TryState copyWith({File? imageFile, File? imageLogo}) {
    return TryState(
      imageFile: imageFile ?? this.imageFile,
      imageLogo: imageLogo ?? this.imageLogo,
    );
  }
}

class TryController extends StateNotifier<TryState> {
  TryController() : super(TryState());
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

  void pickLogoImage() async {
    final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image != null) {
      state = state.copyWith(imageFile: File(image.path));
      print("Image picked for imageFile: ${image.path}");
    }
  }

  // To pick imageLogo (second image)
  void pickLogo() async {
    final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image != null) {
      state = state.copyWith(imageLogo: File(image.path));
      print("Image picked for imageLogo: ${image.path}");
    }
  }

  void removeLogoImage() {
    state = state.copyWith(imageFile: null);
    print("Removed imageFile");
  }

  void removeLogo() {
    state = state.copyWith(imageLogo: null);
    print("Removed imageLogo");
  }
}


Even when i trigger removeLogoImage the image is not removing from UI
When I add an image from the gallery as a file and later set the image to null, it is not removed from the UI. Although the function is called, and the state is updated, the image still remains visible in the UI. How can I make sure the image is removed from the UI when set to null?

I think you should try     final tryController = ref.wathc(tryProvider.notifier); and print  tryController.Logo image if is updating here or not while removing the image. .

TryState copyWith({File? imageFile, File? imageLogo}) {
    return TryState(
      imageFile: imageFile ?? this.imageFile,
      imageLogo: imageLogo ?? this.imageLogo,
    );
  }

You are getting the state logo of logo provided is null. So,
void removeLogoImage() {
    state = state.copyWith(imageFile: null);
    print("Removed imageFile");
  }

setting null will no nothing. It will just set the state value.
In case of null variable in CopyWith function, you should create and use a Wrapped type.
Solution:
Create a Wrapped class to handle null value
class Wrapped<T> {
  final T value;
  const Wrapped.value(this.value);
}

Update your copyWith function to accept Wrapped type value
TryState copyWith({Wrapped<File?>? imageFile, Wrapped<File?>? imageLogo}) {
        return TryState(
          imageFile: imageFile != null ? imageFile.value : this.imageFile,
          imageLogo: imageLogo != null ? imageLogo.value : this.imageLogo,
        );
      }

pass wrapped value while setting new value in copywith
void removeLogoImage() {
    state = state.copyWith(imageFile:Wrapped.value(null);
    print("Removed imageFile");
  }

